# Integration of Amazon Cognito with Ionic for offline sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, mobile, synchronization

I have searched a lot but i cannot find any article on integrating amazon cognito with Ionic using cordova for offline sync , is it possible to integrate apache cordova with cognito for offline sync

Answer (score -2):

In this blog post, the author goes over the main steps to submit events to Amazon Mobile Analytics using PhoneGap as an example. The same general steps can be applied to any framework built around JavaScript such as AppGyver(supersonic), Appcelerator, Ionic, Famo.us, Intel XDK, and web pages.

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCMBFPXR2XWOF/Use-Amazon-Mobile-Analytics-with-your-JavaScript-enabled-apps